# Geoserver H2 datastore trying to connect to old private IP and failing/timing-out

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, connection

Restarted my ubuntu EC2 instance, which changed its' private IP

Tried to preview a geo-server image-mosaic layer which was using the H2 datastore

Kept on getting this exception -

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port H2 TCP Server (tcp://old-ip:41023) (port may be in use), cause: timeout [90061-119]
```

where old-ip is the machine IP before the restart

Answer (score 2):

Looks like "somewhere", the old IP was getting cached

Had to specify  -Dh2.bindAddress=localhost in the geoserver startup script and that fixed the issue